# git subtree/submodule a file from a repository and update it

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

Let's say that I am keeping my zsh dotfiles in a repo:

```
$  tree -a -F .
.
├── .zlogin
├── .zsh/
│   ├── some-dir/
│   │   └── another-script.zsh
│   └── some-script.zsh
└── .zshrc
```

and I am interesting in using a subdirectory from another project, for example directory `lib` from [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/lib) and put it in my `.zsh` folder.

The ending result should be something like this:

```
$  tree -a -F .
.
├── .zlogin
├── .zsh/
│   ├── lib/
│   │   ├── bzr.zsh
│   │   ├── clipboard.zsh
│   │   ├── compfix.zsh
│   │   ├── completion.zsh
│   │   ├── correction.zsh
│   │   ├── diagnostics.zsh
│   │   ├── directories.zsh
│   │   ├── functions.zsh
│   │   ├── git.zsh
│   │   ├── grep.zsh
│   │   ├── history.zsh
│   │   ├── key-bindings.zsh
│   │   ├── misc.zsh
│   │   ├── nvm.zsh
│   │   ├── prompt_info_functions.zsh
│   │   ├── spectrum.zsh
│   │   ├── termsupport.zsh
│   │   └── theme-and-appearance.zsh
│   ├── some-dir/
│   │   └── another-script.zsh
│   └── some-script.zsh
└── .zshrc
```

but I don't want to just download & copy the directory, I want to be able to automatically update it without having to keep the whole oh-my-zsh repo on my project. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple, but kludgy answer and a more "elegant", but complex answer.

My kludgy solution is to put the whole oh-my-zsh repo in a submodule within a top-level folder like "subs" or something like that. Then symlink to the lib directory from within your .zsh directory...

```
user@host:~/.zsh>  ln -s ../subs/oh-my-zsh/lib
```

Yeah, I feel like I should wash my hands after typing such an answer. The arguably more elegant option involves a sparse checkout of a submodule with specific folders set to visible. Here is an [excellent explanation](http://kshmakov.org/notes/th/2/) of this approach.

Unfortunately, I don't think the sparse checkout will work in your specific case because you want the lib directory to reside within the .zsh directory which is part of your repository. As far as I know, you can't have your own code inside a submodule without committing the changes to the submodule repo. Having said that, this is Git we're talking about and Git is magical enough that it may have a way to do this.

If it were me, I'd kludge it and call it good.  :)